# Why a serialized object is different from the original?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I try to create a program to compare 2 objects. If I create 2 instances of the same object, the 2 objects are differents because, even if they have the same "tin", they are 2 individuals objects.

But, in my case, I create an object, serialize it, deserialize it into a second instance and compare the original with the copy.

Why are they different ? I don't even use "new" to create the second instance. I just read the serialized object...
Here are the 2 classes I use :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("something.serial");

    //Creation of the 1st object
    Something obj1 = new Something();

    //Serialization
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try {
        oos= new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(file)));
        oos.writeObject(obj1);
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Second object
    Something obj2=null;

    //Deserialization
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(file));
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        obj2=(Something)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Compare
    if (obj1.equals(obj2)) {
        System.out.println("Same");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Different : ");
        System.out.println(obj1.toString()+" - "+obj2.toString());
    }
}
}
```

and :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Something implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int value = 2;

Something () {

}
}
```

Thank you for all your answers that will help me to understand.

Comment: how do you implement the equals method in your Something class? If you don't override it at all it doesn't compare your objects correctly obviously and equals returns false.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't understand what **equals()** really does. Therefore: learn about that; and then implement your own equals() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, when u serialize it, the state of the object is being saved to a file, not the memory location.
When you deserialize it, a new object with the same state is being created internally and a reference to it is being passed to you.

As you have not overridden the `equals()` method, it is checking only if the memory address is the same.

Override the `.equals()` method and check whether the states are same yourself.